# Why are language-specific programs frequently written in the same language they are designed for?

Tags: language-agnostic, theory, bootstrapping

I was browsing about to learn what language software I frequently use is written in, and found an interesting trend. Programs that are designed for a specific language tend to have a significant portion of themselves written in that language. For example:

- Eclipse is written in Java
- Visual Studio in C# and C++
- [dart-fmt](https://github.com/dart-lang/dart_style) (which is what prompted this question) is written in Dart

I understand the reasoning behind bootstrapping specifically in regards to compilers, but since the examples I gave are IDEs or other tools and specifically *not* compilers, why would they choose to write the applications in the language they are designed for? What is the benefit to writing these applications in the language that they are being designed for?

Answer (score 1):

This has no relation, it's more or less a coincidence.
I write a lot of C/C++ PHP, in eclipse, and quite happy with the results.

Of course, there is probably some other logic out there also. I mean, i am not sure here (but mostly guessing). For a programmer to write a good IDE for a certain language that programmer's best language should be that. So if i write a Java IDE, i would have indepth knowledge of Java, and generally if i write software i chose the easiest/fastest route to achieving the ends. And in this scenario using Java for eclipse would make sense - but there is nothing more to it than that.